# <form> is not working with mootools

Tags: php, mootools

I have following code in my php file

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['updatebtn']))
{
mysql_query("update table......");
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){

        new FormCheck('myform');
    });
</script>

<form name="myform" method="post" id="myform" action="">

<input type="text" class="validate['required']" />

<input type="submit" value="updatebtn" />
</form>
```

as you can see i have added mootools form validation in my file. mootools form validation work only if i add `id="myform"` in my form. but if i add that (i. e. id="myform"), it is creating problem, means it is not executing update query that i have written at top.

if i remove id="myform" from my form tag, it is executing that update query

do anyone have any idea??

Comment: @ManojNakum: uhm `value="updatebtn"` shouldn't that be `name="updatebtn"`?

Comment: sorry for that, but both value and name are same

Comment: plus: shouldn't the form have an attribute `method="post"`? otherwise `$_POST` is never set.

Comment: [I've tried it](http://codepad.org/T1BxFRef) and it worked without problems. If the text-field was empty and I tried to submit it nothing happened (which is probably by design). But if I entered some text the form was submitted and "UPDATE" was displayed.

Comment: but when i'm submitting the page, it is redirected to the some 'post' that not in my site, so it is giving object not found error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6140/discussion-between-manoj-nakum-and-vstm)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript would validate the input and prevent the form to submitting so it's normal that your server side script won't run.

I think you should make a difference between things run on server side, such as PHP and things run on client side, i.e. javascript.

Comment: i didn't get you RageZ, could you please explain it in more detail please